# "Empy Trash" opens Nautilus (Files) window

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, trash

When trying to empty the Trash (right-clicking on the Trash icon in the launcher and then selecting "Empty Trash"), a new window of Nautilus opens (working directory `~`).

Is this a bug? Are there any workarounds or fixes a user could make?

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1448229

Comment: ok. should I remove my question now?

Comment: I would leave it open so that people could add eventually existing workarounds as answers. Btw I experience the same behavior...

Comment: It's a feature, they bound the opening of the `~` folder to some completely unrelated events to accomodate the cases in which you need to browse it right after. (Same here using `nautilus` 3.14.2)

Comment: I have same issue on ubuntu 15.04. , as @abhishek said it is a bug and reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1448229 and might be duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1445595

Answer (score 0):

For now open terminal :

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

Comment: Did that, the folders get recreated (expunged, files, info) and the new nautilus windows is still opended... So, this workaround is not working, unless I am missing something!

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work at all...

Comment: @SuperMau this is not a fix for making 'empty trash' work, but rather the command to empty the trash manually. Running it will empty the trash once, and do nothing more.